# Erro de precisão em conta com BigDecimal

Tags: java

Tenho a classe abaixo, que apresenta um valor diferente de quando uso a calculadora. Pesquisei sobre `BigDecimal`, mas devo estar errando em algo na hora de apresentar o resultado.

Aconta que tenho que fazer é:

> 4.5% de 8410 = 378,45

Mas usando a classe abaixo é apresenta apenas 378 . As casas decimais não estou sabendo exibir.

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal valorInicial = new BigDecimal("8410");
        BigDecimal contanteDivisor = new BigDecimal("100");
        BigDecimal resultDivisao = valorInicial.divide(contanteDivisor, new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
        BigDecimal resultado = resultDivisao.multiply(new BigDecimal("4.50"));

        System.out.println("Resultado: " + resultado);           
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remova o `MathContext`:

```
public class Teste {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal valorInicial = new BigDecimal("8410");
        BigDecimal contanteDivisor = new BigDecimal("100");
        BigDecimal resultDivisao = valorInicial.divide(contanteDivisor);
        BigDecimal resultado = resultDivisao.multiply(new BigDecimal("4.50"));

        System.out.println("Resultado: " + resultado);           
    }    
}
```

Ao adicionar `new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)` na chamada do `BigDecimal`, você está dizendo para ele que arredonde o valor da divisão para o número mais próximo, considerando até dois dígitos de precisão.

Com isso, ao dividir *8410* por *100* conforme o trecho do seu código abaixo:

```
BigDecimal valorInicial = new BigDecimal("8410");
BigDecimal contanteDivisor = new BigDecimal("100");
BigDecimal resultDivisao = valorInicial.divide(contanteDivisor, new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
```

`resultDivisao` deveria ser *84.10*, mas com o arrendondamento utilizando uma precisão de apenas dois digitos o resultado é *84*.

Veja no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/3WvaEj) a diferença entre os quocientes, com e sem o arredondamento.

Na linha seguinte,

```
BigDecimal resultado = resultDivisao.multiply(new BigDecimal("4.50"));
```

Você está multiplicando na verdade *84* por *4.5*, que resulta nos *378* que seu código está exibindo, e não no resultado esperado(*84.10 * 4.50 = 378.45*);

---

É importante destacar que se a intenção do código era limitar o número de casas decimais do resultado da divisão, deve-se utilizar o método `setScale`, pois estamos falando da escala (dígitos após a vírgula) e não de precisão (dígitos significativos).

Para isso, você pode adaptar a linha da divisão conforme abaixo:

```
BigDecimal resultDivisao = valorInicial.divide(contanteDivisor)
        .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Quando o resultado da divisão pode ser um número não exato é necessário trabalhar também com uma precisão para evitar uma `ArithmeticException`. O ajuste de escala pode ser feito após a divisão:

```
BigDecimal valorInicial = new BigDecimal("8411");
BigDecimal contanteDivisor = new BigDecimal("101");
BigDecimal resultDivisao = valorInicial
        .divide(contanteDivisor, new MathContext(10, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN))
        .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Nesse caso o resultado da divisão de *8411* por *101* com precisão de 10 dígitos é *83.27722772*. Após o ajuste de escala o resultado final é *83.28*.

Ou seja, a precisão estabelece o número de dígitos a serem computados enquanto a escala ajusta a quantidade de casas decimais.

Veja o código corrigido executando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/agdNY6).

Referências:

[Documentação: RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

[Documentação: BigDecimal.setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20java.math.RoundingMode))

[BigDecimal setScale and round](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13461270/5524514)

Comment: Muito obrigada !